# How to use TextEncoder and TextDecoder from bootstrap addon

Tags: file-io, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

Following OS.file example it uses TextEncoder however from bootstrap scope this is not available.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File/OS.File_for_the_main_thread#Example.3A_Read_the_contents_of_a_file_as_text

Only way I could access it is by going `decoder = new Services.appShell.hiddenDOMWindow.TextDecoder();` but is thi the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TextEncoder` and friends inside a javascript module. But doing so might be an overkill, if all you want is a couple of missing globals (putting aside the fact that `jsm` are cached and this might not work well with a restartless addon).

Conveniently Addon SDK's loader delivers what you need.

```js
const { TextDecoder, TextEncoder } = Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js', {});
```

Comment: Thanks paa! This does the trick! I don't understand your first line? Do you mean if I made a .jsm it has access to TextEncoder?

Comment: Yes, the code context of a `jsm` has access to the (mozilla) JS globals